# How to get notified when my windows server reboot unexpectedly

Tags: windows, windows-services, windows-server-2012

Is there any way to get email notified when windows server rebooted itself unexpectedly (like powercut off). i would like to add some batch script in startup services.

Note: without any monitering tools.

Answer (score -1):

**Run a batch file at loading of Windows 8 and 10:**

```
1) Create a shortcut to the batch file. (batch file should have how you want to do during build)
2) Press Start, type Run, and press Enter.
3) In the Run window, type "shell:startup" to open the Startup folder.
```

> shell:startup

```
 4) Once the Startup folder is opened, click the Home tab at the top of the folder. Then, select Paste to paste the shortcut file into the Startup folder.
```

> CALL C:\Yourbatch.bat